# Meaning of "suck on their fingers" in "Everyone Cried" by Lydia Davis

Tags: meaning, short-stories

In the following quote from "[Everyone Cried](https://www.newyorker.com/books/flash-fiction/everyone-cried)" by Lydia Davis, what does "suck on their fingers" mean? What is the author trying to convey here? Are they literally sucking on their fingers? Why would an adult do that? (It's a sad story and people are constantly crying and upset)

> Some people would gradually stop crying as they rode toward home, especially
> if they had found a seat. They would blink their damp eyelashes and
> contentedly suck on their fingers as they read their newspapers and books, their eyes still shining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story basically describes an infantilised world where adults are not self regulating their behaviour in a way we would normally expect, they instead behave as children, being grumpy when they are tired, hungry or frustrated. This may be a comment on societal effects a perceived reduction in people's attention spans or ability to cope with [stimulus overload](https://bhatpsych.com/attention-spans-in-the-age-of-technology/) or delays in gratification which may result from the degree of exposure to digital media and online communication:

> Dr. Richard Restak’s book The New Brain: How the Modern Age Is Rewiring Your Mind covers this topic in depth. He discusses how we are all capable of reaching a breaking point where we lose our ability to focus due to overstimulation. This is what could be happening with many of our children. A child who is seen as “having difficulty focusing” or “bright, but not working to his full potential” may be unable to keep up with the demands of a stimulus-filled environment.

The finger sucking fits directly into that as a form of self soothing.

While it is more usual for people to refer to babies sucking their thumbs, this self soothing action can also feature sucking fingers or other parts of the hand or body, I sucked my index finger as a child rather than my thumb and my mother, right up into her twenties had a self soothing habit of sucking on her own tongue (no, I didn't understand quite what it was she was doing, but that's what she called it. She was an inveterate napper and she could send her self to sleep in seconds by deploying the technique).

Lots of baby websites will tell you about thumb sucking, but I'm quoting from this one as it recognises that thumbs are not the only suckable digits:

> sucking on their hand may be a sign of self-soothing. Young babies often fall asleep on the breast or bottle, so they may come to associate the sucking reflex with the initial stages of sleep and suck on their hand to help them relax and wind down.
>
> You may also see older babies — in the 7 to 8-month range — sucking on hands or fingers for the same reason: It produces a calming sensation that relaxes them.
> [Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/baby/baby-sucking-on-hand#reasons)